# How do I get a type for a given polymorphic function and expression?

Tags: haskell, typing

Here's the exam question that prompted this post:

## Exam Question:

Consider the following definition of binary trees in Haskell.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Leaf a | Node (Tree a) a (Tree a)
```

According to this declaration, trees can be: `Empty`, a `Leaf` containing an element of type `a`, or a `Node` containing an element of type `a` and two `Tree`s.

For example, the following expressions have type `Tree Int`:

```
Leaf 0

Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Leaf 3)
```

The following function flattens a `Tree` to a list of elements (recall that `++` is the concatenation operator for lists in Haskell).

```
flatten Empty = [ ]
flatten (Leaf l) = [l]
flatten (Node t1 r t2) = (flatten t1) ++ (r : (flatten t2))
```

*i. Give a polymorphic type for the function `flatten`. Justify your answer.*

*ii. Give a type for the expression:*

```
flatten (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Leaf 3))
```

*Justify your answer.*

## My Question

I think I understand the theory here, it's clear that `flatten`, in order to do its job, accepts multiple types (`[ ]`, `Leaf` and `Node`) but how am I supposed to interpret it's type from that? Unless I am to assume that `flatten` is of the same type that it accepts, I'm not sure where to go from here.

Regarding the second part of the question, are there different types for `flatten` depending on whether or not it's in the form of an *expression*? If so, I feel like I'm right in my assumption in the last paragraph, but I'd like to have the comfort of actual logic on my side than simply guessing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is about the basics of the Haskell language, not about its type theory, so I'm migrating it to a site about programming.

Comment: Repost of a comment by [Anton Trunov](http://cs.stackexchange.com/users/39226/anton-trunov) that was automatically deleted during the migration: “`Leaf 0`'s (and the next tree's) type is not `Tree Int` in Haskell, its' `Leaf 0 :: Num a => Tree a`. **(3)** `[]`, `Leaf` and `Node` are not types, but constructors. **(4)** You can always find out the type of an expression by firing up `ghci` and making a request like this`λ> :t flatten` or `λ> :t flatten (Node (Leaf 1) 2 (Leaf 3))` (it doesn't give explanations, but it's a sure way to check yourself).”

Answer (score 2):

To properly understand the question, you should know about [type inference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_inference)
and [difference between type and data constructor](https://wiki.haskell.org/Constructor). Haskell uses type inferring algorithm, however the exam question is phrased as it's knowledge is not necessary and intuition sufficient. It's also useful to know that if you type `:t <expression>` in GHCI, it will give you the type.

In this particular example your definition creates four constructors - unary type constructor `Tree`, nullary data `Empty`, unary data `Leaf`, and ternary data `Node`.

Now, we look at the function. Function has three definitions based on what gets pattern matched, however we know that each definition has to have the same type (or be unifiable with other types). From the first line

```
flatten Empty = [ ]
```

we can see that flatten takes some `Empty` (what we know is a `Tree`'s data constructor), and returns an `[]`, what is a list. However, `Tree` is parametrized type. `Empty` however makes no use of the parametrization, and therefor it can belong to any `Tree` - a polymorfous type `Tree a`. The `[]` is a list. Lists are generally of type `[a]`, `a` being the type of list's members. There are no members in empty list, and so the list's type is polymorfous - stays `[a]`. We however said the `a` comes from the `Tree` parameter, and there is nothing in this line of definition that says the members of list comes from the tree, so we can give it other name, let's go with `b`. From the first line we therefor deduced that the type is `Tree a -> [b]`, or something that can be unified.

From the second line

`flatten (Leaf l) = [l]`

We see that `flatten` takes some `Leaf`, parametrized with `l`. We know that `Leaf l` is a data constructor of a `Tree a`, and we know that `l` is type of `a`. So the function takes some `Tree a` again. It return a list of a single element, the `l`. We know that `l` is type of `a`, so the list has to be type `[a]`. The whole type is `Tree a -> [a]`.

We can take this type and unify it whit what we got from the first line. If the `Tree a -> [b]` should be the same as `Tree a -> [a]`, we see that `a` has to be the same as `b`. So we unify. We should look at the third line, but in this case the type will not be unified further.

One more thing. If we had definition like this:

```
flatten Empty = ['e']
flatten (Leaf l) = [l]
flatten (Node t1 r t2) = (flatten t1) ++ (r : (flatten t2))
```

we would see from the first line, that the resulting type is an array of chars `[Char]` (or `String`, it's an alias). The function type would be `Tree a -> [Char]`. After taking into consideration the second line, and seeing the array contains what the leaf contains, after the unification we have to assume the tree contains only chars, and the type of function would be `Tree Char -> [Char]`.

Answer (score 1):

> it's clear that `flatten`, in order to do its job, accepts multiple types (`[ ]`, `Leaf` and `Node`)

I don't understand why you think that `flatten` accepts `[ ]`. I'm not even sure what you mean by this; `[ ]` isn't a type, it's a type constructor, that takes a type `a` as an argument and returns the type `[a]` “list whose elements are of type `a`”.

The three clauses that define `flatten` all make it a function that takes one argument, so it has a type of the form `x -> y` where `x` is the type of the argument and `y` is the return type. In each case, the argument is formed by applying a constructor of the `Tree` type constructor, so the argument has a type of the form `Tree w`. The return value in the first clause is `[]` so its type is of the form `[z]`. So far, we know that the most general type of `flatten` is of the form `Tree w -> [z]`. The second clause `flatten (Leaf l) = [l]` provides an additional constraint `w = z`, because the type of `l` comes up on both sides, so the most general type is of the form `Tree z -> [z]`.

This is in fact a valid type for `flatten`, so `Tree z -> [z]` is the most general type of `flatten`. To see this, you need to go through the whole definition and check that it doesn't impose any additional constraint on `z`.

This is a polymorphic type: it contains the type variable `z`. This variable can be instantiated by any type. For example, `flatten (Leaf (1 :: Int))` uses `flatten` with the type `Tree Int -> [Int]`, while `flatten (Leaf True)` uses `flatten` with the type `Tree Bool -> [Bool]`.

The fact that `flatten` is polymorphic is not due to its being a function. Applying it to an argument doesn't change the type of `flatten`, but it may not use it in its full generality. The type of the resulting expression can still be polymorphic. For example, the type of `\x -> flatten x` is `Tree a -> [a]` for all `a`, same as `flatten`, unsurprisingly since `\x -> flatten x` is equivalent to `flatten`.

The type of `flatten (Leaf 3)` results from three constraints: `flatten` with an argument type of the form `Tree a` has the return type `[a]`, `Leaf` accepts any type `a` and returns a `Tree a`, and `3` has the type `Num a => a`, i.e. `3` has any type `a` provided that this type is an instance of the `Num` class. So `flatten (Leaf 3)` has the type `[a]` under the constraint that `a` is an instance of `Num`, i.e. `flatten (Leaf 3)` has the most general type `Num a => [a]`.